# How to run_command at setuptools with options?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have two custom commands at [my setup.py file:](https://github.com/quasiyoke/vk_relations/blob/ac2996d65d7311f398e12734adfa03a25cc58454/setup.py) `create_tables` and `drop_tables`:

```
class create_tables(command):
    description = 'create DB tables'

    user_options = [
        ('database=', 'd', 'which database configuration use'),
        ('reset', 'r', 'reset all data previously'),
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        command.initialize_options(self)
        self.reset = False

    def run(self):
        if self.reset:
            self.run_command('drop_tables')
        else:
            command.run(self)
        from vk_relations import models
        models.create_tables()
        print 'Tables were created successfully'


class drop_tables(command):
    description = 'drop all created DB tables'

    user_options = [
        ('database=', 'd', 'which database configuration use'),
    ]

    def run(self):
        command.run(self)
        answer = raw_input('Are you sure you want to clear all VK Relations data? (y/n): ')
        if 'y' == answer:
            from vk_relations import models
            models.drop_tables()
            print 'Tables were dropped successfully'
        elif 'n' == answer:
            quit()
        else:
            sys.exit()
```

Command `$ setup.py create_tables -r -dmain` should run command `drop_tables` and create new tables at `main` database, but `run_command` method doesn't allow to provide options to the command. How to specify option `database` for `drop_tables` inside `create_tables` command?

Answer (score 4):

Right now I've used this hack:

```python
cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj('drop_tables')
cmd_obj.database = self.database
self.run_command('drop_tables')
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The "proper" solution

Setting attributes on the objects will fail for the pre-defined targets such as `build`.
The closest you can get here to a proper solution is following:

```
class drop_tables(command): # <-- Note this should come from drop_tables command

    def finalize_options(self):
        self.set_undefined_options("create_tables", ("database", "database"))
```

This is the approach used to inherit arguments from `build` to `build_py` and other subcommands.

#### On the `build` command

I do not fancy the circular reference the authors of the `distutils` package introduced in the build command.
The execution order there is following: the `build` command calls the `build_py` subcommand. The subcommand goes back to the `build` command and gets the parameters that are left undefined. This makes tight coupling because both commands need to know about each other.
Also if another aggregate command were to be added the ambiguity would be introduced - the `build_py` would have two sources of parameters to inherit.

The approach that would reduce the coupling should be different.
If the `build` command is an aggregate command and therefore it should handle all the parameter passing to its subcommands.

```
class build(command):
    ...
    def finalize_options(self):
        for cmd_name in self.get_sub_commands():
            cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(cmd_name)
            cmd_obj.set_undefined_options("build", ("build_lib", "build_lib"), ...)
```

Now there's no need to pass command by name and we can use instance instead. This would also resolve the infinite recursion in `set_undefined_options` > `ensure_finalized` > `finalize_options` > `set_undefined_options`

#### The proper solution

Given the current state of affairs the better solutions for you problem would be:

```
class create_tables(command):

    def run(self):
        cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj("drop_tables")
        cmd_obj.set_undefined_options("create_tables", ("database", "database"))
        self.run_command("drop_tables")
```